# Class property doesn't apply to an element on the wordpress page

Tags: css, class, frontend

I'm trying to set the height of each image section to 10px with the following class that doesn't seem to work. Please tell what is missing here from the screenshot of the most of the HTML below.

```
.ff-el-form-check .ff-el-form-check- .ff-el-image-holder {
    height: 10px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If it's the same element then remove the spaces between the classes

Comment: Removing spaces made images overlap, resulting in one row.

Comment: You are putting the images in as backgrounds so the width of the label will not automatically expand to give space for the image. Is there something in your CSS which sets the width of a label, or do you want each label to have enough width to show a complete image at height 10px or.... We need to see the relevant CSS and to understand how you want the labels to look - complete or partial image.